# Tizen web app - navigate plain web page with remote

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I’m working on a Tizen web app where we have our own navigation system able to use input from the remote or gamepad. We also have a feature to open a new page linking to an external URL (e.g. support / registration), done with a plain `<a target="_self">` link.

My problem is that this new page cannot be navigated at all with the remote. Only a physical mouse appears to work. The same URL opened in the regular Internet app can be navigated with remote-controlled virtual mouse.

Is there a way to either activate the virtual mouse, or get the URL to open in the Internet app?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From app main page, not navigating to external URL page or external URL page is not navigating with virtual remote?

Trying to access external url, so are you added below line in config.xml for cross origin request.
access origin="*"

Comment: The external URL page does open - we have the correct settings in `config.xml` - but indeed after that it's not possible to use the remote to interact with the page elements.

Typical example : the external URL page opens to a manage-your-cookie-preferences popup and there's just no way to go click on the close button unless there's an actual, physical mouse connected to the device.


At this point we have replaced opening extermal URLs with a plain QR code for the user to scan on a separate device, but I'd still be interested if there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed by Samsung rules to open external links from your application inside the application. Very recently they allowed to open external link in their Native browser app, but you can't control any behaviour there.

My suggestion is to use iframe inside your app. Then you will have to implement only iFrame focus and blur functions inside your app.

Also, if it's an external link on different domain you might need to use [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to be able to communicate between your app and iFrame.

Comment: How is using an iFrame not breaking the rules set by Samsung? It's still opening external links within the app which is against the defaultT&Cs set by Samsung. Permission needs to be granted by Samsung specifically for the app. It's not necessary either. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to navigate normally if you add the following tags to the app config.xml

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
```